# n or nvm for managing node versions - is keeping global modules for each version a good idea?

Tags: node.js

I've been using docker containers for node, unfortunatly on OSX `gulp watch` is super slow and buggy. So I'm back to installing tools on host machine :( unfortunatly.

Choosing between `n` and `nvm`

One major difference I see between these is the global packages, `n` keeps single global repo for all versions, and `nvm` keeps em separate.

Not having worked on many node.js projects, I have a feeling this is an important distinction, but I'm not sure if it really matters in real life.

any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`n` is a Node module, which can be installed by npm, and `nvm` is a Bash script.

`n` and `nvm` are both still active projects, because it's still more of a bother than updating on Windows. They are still actively maintained, and both have been modified less than 10 days ago.

I find `n` to be of easier use because it can be installed by npm, but both scripts serve their purpose ;)

Comment: yes that is clear to me. I had specific question about global packages. NVM keeps them separate and N doesn't.

Comment: It depends here, if you wanna keep an structure into your app use `nvm`, but if you don't care too much since it won't affect production, you could use `n` as well ;)

Comment: "if you wanna keep an structure into your app" is so vague. What do you mean exactly by this sentence?

Comment: I find n easier too and I chose it after tried both. I prefer handle node versions for production project with docker containers. In this way others people are working on the project are free to use install n or nvm on the his machine. Today docker on Mac is working better that 3 years ago

Comment: In case it interests anyone, I wrote a tutorial on how to install n and upgrade node and npm in Ubuntu/Linux Mint/Debian etc. https://askubuntu.com/a/1403000/808646

Comment: I don't recommend using `n` because it manages only the system-wide Node version, preventing different projects running with different Node versions same time. `nvm` or `volta` allows for project-based or global Node version management. I am currently using `volta` as its super easy to use. `asdf` is another popular node version manager that also allows you to manage other runtime versions like Java, Python, etc.

Answer (score 26):

I will say if you don't need to work on different node versions and switch back and forth, n is far easier. For example when you use nvm to switch to a different node version all the global packages with the old version were "gone", you will have to install them again for the new version, for a production env it is a good thing but for the dev env it is quite annoying.

I have a project that started with node 6 (mac & Ubuntu) and in the past 2 years all I did was to first upgrade to node 8 (mainly to use async/await to avoid callback hell) then to node 10 (mainly to get a better performance with latest V8 Engine). I tried nvm and n and n is definitely easier.

---- update 2020.11.16 ----

After gaining more experience with n I do find n has an annoying problem: when n install failed (maybe due to network problem), it will also **corrupt my existing node**, following is an example. I have to reinstall node then.

```
AES-demo ➤ sudo n lts                                                                                                                               
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to nodejs.org:443

  Error: failed to download version index (https://nodejs.org/dist/index.tab)

// I guess it was due to the network failure because it then succeeded
AES-demo ➤ sudo n lts                                                                                                                                 

  installing : node-v14.15.1
....

//But then I hit the error, which means node was broken
/usr/local/bin/n: line 636: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
AES-demo ➤ node -v                                                                                                                                    
zsh: command not found: node
```

I opened an issue against n https://github.com/tj/n/issues/634.

The problem is fixed in "Improvement released in v6.7.1." So be sure to install this latest version (as in 2020.11.23)

Comment: The following will make it less of an annoyance though: `nvm install --lts --reinstall-packages-from=OLD_VERSION` or `nvm reinstall-packages <version>`